# Creating 28$\times$28 matrix whose entries are Levi Civita tensors

Tags: matrix, tensors

I would like to create a particular 28$\times$ 28 matrix whose entries are given by

$$ X_{[ij][kl]} = \delta^{[ij][kl]}_{1234} + \delta^{[ij][kl]}_{5678}$$

where $\delta^{ijkl}_{abcd} = \begin{cases} +1 & \text{if $ijkl$ is an even permutation of $abcd$}\\ -1 & \text{if $ijkl$ is an odd permutation of $abcd$} \\0 & \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$

There are several tricky features about this matrix, making it hard to be implemented in Mathematica.

1. The entries of $X$ are labeled by antisymmetric pairs $[ij]$ where $i,j$ (individually) run from 1 to 8, but when they are combined in antisymmetric pairs, there are 28 combinations (here organised into 7 blocks, each 4$\times$ 4):  (12, 34, 56, 78); (13, 24, 57, 68); (14, 23, 58, 67); (15, 26, 37, 48); (16, 25, 38, 47); (17, 28, 35, 46); (18, 27, 36, 45)
2. So basically, X is of block-diagonal form, with 7 blocks with entries labeled as above. So to calculate the entries, one uses 4-dimensional Levi-civita tensors for each entry. The only way I know to create this 28$\times$28 matrix would be to enter each entry individually using the `Signature[{i,j,k,l}]` function. 
   This would repeat for the rest of the 6 remaining diagonal blocks (all entries corresponding to elements of different blocks vanish), and it is rather tedious.

So I'd be very grateful if someone could come up with a smart way to do this ?

Answer (score 6):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
n = 8;
idx = Flatten[Table[{i, j}, {i, 1, n}, {j, i + 1, n}], 1];
list1 = Range[1, 4];
list2 = Range[5, 8];

A = Table[
   With[
    {c = Join[a, b]},
    With[
      {d = Sort[c]},
      Signature[c] (Boole[d == list1] + Boole[d == list2])
      ]
    ],
   {a, idx}, {b, idx}];
```

Comment: Thank you for your code ! I am trying to understand it and check to see what modifications are needed if I have to generate the following 28$\times$28 matrices: $X^{[ij][kl]}_2 = \delta^{[ij][kl]}_{1256} + \delta^{[ij][kl]}_{3478}$,  $X^{[ij][kl]}_3= \delta^{[ij][kl]}_{1458} + \delta^{[ij][kl]}_{2367}$

Comment: For the first new case, you simply have to replace `list1` and `list2` by `{1,2,5,6}` and `{3,4,7,8}`, respectively.

Comment: I re-ran the code on my home laptop, which only has Mathematica 8, I got the following error messages:    With::argrx: With called with 3 arguments; 2 arguments are expected. >>General::stop: Further output of With::argrx will be suppressed during this calculation. >>. This code worked fine on my work laptop with Mathematica 11, so perhaps these are due to Mathematica 8?

Comment: The multi-argument version of `With` was only introduced recently and isn't documented. I shouldn't have used it. I removed it from the post. Please try again.

Comment: It works on Mathematica 8 now ! Thanks so much ! I'd like to confirm that the label for the entries follow your defined idx, they're increasing from 12, 13, 14, ...., 67, 68, 78, right? There is no way to re-organize those into the block diagonal form of the 7 blocks listed in my question? I ask this because I have another nasty 28$\times$ 28 matrix that I have to generate, which is a sum of 7 terms: $Y = \delta_{1234} + \delta_{1256} + \delta_{1278} + \delta_{1375} + \delta_{1368} + \delta_{1458} + \delta_{1467}$, and this Y matrix will probably look neat in the block diagonal form.

Comment: Btw, I generated the Y matrix using your code with some additions: idx = Flatten[Table[{i, j}, {i, 1, n}, {j, i + 1, n}], 1]
list1 = {1, 2, 3, 4};
list2 = {1, 2, 5, 6};
list3 = {1, 2, 7, 8};
list4 = {1, 3, 7, 5};
list5 = {1, 3, 6, 8};
list6 = {1, 4, 5, 8};
list7 = {1, 4, 6, 7};
A = Table[
  With[{c = Join[a, b]}, 
   With[{d = Sort[c]}, 
    Signature[
      c] (Boole[d == list1] + Boole[d == list2] + Boole[d == list3] + 
       Boole[d == list4] + Boole[d == list5] + Boole[d == list6] + 
       Boole[d == list7])]], {a, idx}, {b, idx}] and it works perfectly ! Thanks again.

Comment: I also re-organized the labels manually to get the block-diagonal form: idx = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}, {7, 8}, {1, 3}, {2, 4}, {5, 7}, {6, 
    8}, {1, 4}, {2, 3}, {5, 8}, {6, 7}, {1, 5}, {2, 6}, {3, 7}, {4, 
    8}, {1, 6}, {2, 5}, {3, 8}, {4, 7}, {1, 7}, {2, 8}, {3, 5}, {4, 
    6}, {1, 8}, {2, 7}, {3, 6}, {4, 5}};

Comment: So you managed to achieve that on your own. That's great! You know best which ordering to use. And you're welcome.

Answer (score 5):

If you have M9+, you could use [`SymmetrizedArray`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SymmetrizedArray) to create an $8 \times 8 \times 8\times8$ dimensional array with the desired symmetry:

```
X = SymmetrizedArray[
    {{1,2,3,4}->1, {5,6,7,8}->1},
    {8,8,8,8},
    Antisymmetric[{1,2,3,4}]
];
```

To convert this to a $28\times28$ matrix, you would group the first 2 and last 2 dimensions:

```
Y = Flatten[X, {{1,2}, {3,4}}];
```

and then extract the upper right indices:

```
upperRight = Pick[
    Range[64],
    Flatten @ LowerTriangularize[ConstantArray[1, {8,8}]],
    0
]
```

> {2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 29, 30, 31, 32, 38, 39, 40, 47, 48, 56}

to arrive at:

```
Z = Y[[upperRight, upperRight]];
```

This is the same as @Henrik's answer:

```
A == Z
```

> True

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I copied and pasted your code into my Mathematica 8 on my home laptop, and I got the following outputs and error messages: Flatten::fldep: "Level 2 specified in {{1,2},{3,4}} exceeds the levels, 1, which can be flattened together in SymmetrizedArray[{{1,2,3,4}->1,{5,6,7,8}->1},{8,8,8,8},Antisymmetric[{1,2,3,4}]]." I suspect that it is a problem with Mathematica 8, because the same code from Henrik that worked on Mathematica 11 (on my work laptop) ceased to work on Mathematica 8 (on my home laptop)

Comment: Thanks. I should run this code again on my work laptop with M11.